exception occurred in flutter app how i can solved it?

FlutterError (A RenderRepaintBoundary expected a child of type
RenderBox but received a child of type RenderSliverToBoxAdapter.
RenderObjects expect specific types of children because they
coordinate with their children during layout and paint. For example, a
RenderSliver cannot be the child of a RenderBox because a RenderSliver
does not understand the RenderBox layout protocol.
The RenderRepaintBoundary that expected a RenderBox child was created
by:   RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← _SelectionKeepAlive ←
NotificationListener ← KeepAlive ←
AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← Viewport ←
IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#4ddb3] ← Semantics ← Listener ← ⋯
The RenderSliverToBoxAdapter that did not match the expected child
type was created by:   SliverToBoxAdapter ← News_List_View ←
RepaintBoundary ← IndexedSemantics ← _SelectionKeepAlive ←
NotificationListener ← KeepAlive ←
AutomaticKeepAlive ← KeyedSubtree ← SliverList ← Viewport ←
IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#4ddb3] ← ⋯)

This my code i'm already used SliverToBoxAdapter but this exception still
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return isLoading
        ? const  SliverToBoxAdapter(
          child: Center(child:CircularProgressIndicator()))
        : SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(childCount: articles.length,
                (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 22),
              child: NewsTile(
                articleModel: articles[index],
              ),
            );
          }));
  }
}


You have to use like this, Because CustomScrollView is the parent widget that allows the use of slivers, which include SliverList and SliverToBoxAdapter
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return CustomScrollView(
    slivers: [
      SliverToBoxAdapter(
        child: isLoading
            ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
            : SizedBox.shrink(), // Return an empty widget if not loading
      ),
      SliverList(
        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
          childCount: articles.length,
          (context, index) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 22),
              child: NewsTile(
                articleModel: articles[index],
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    ],
  );
}

